# Java game check if shoot fire touched monster is too slow

Tags: java

I've made a simple game, where you are the box and you are shooting little boxes.

Now to check if the shoot tocuhed the monster, i check if its x is highter or equals to the monster's x, and then i check if its less or equals to the monsters x, and then the same for y.

But the thing is, I have two for loops for this, therefore when I shoot and it touched the monster, the monster will not always get deleted cause the for loop did not reach that monster yet, and im sure it's bad for performance.

IS there a faster way to do this? why is it happening?

```
private void checkKilled() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.shoots.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.monsters.size(); j++) {
            Monster m = this.monsters.get(j);
            Shoot s = this.shoots.get(i);
            if (s.getX() >= m.getX() && s.getX() <= m.getX() + 15
                    && s.getY() >= m.getY() && s.getY() <= m.getY() + 15) {
                m.isDead = true;
                s.isExploded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example scenario in which this doesn't work?  It looks completely fine to me.

Comment: Ill try to get Gyazo & take a gif.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It should be fine.You can first check if a monster is currently visible or present on screen

Comment: Is there a UI that runs on another thread? Is the game multithreaded at all? If not, I would guess that the problem isn't that it's too slow, but the shot position skipped the monster. By the way, how many monsters/shots can exist simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding the problem, but for performance you can `break` from inner loop if condition is true; it will then go to next shoot.

```
  ...
  s.isExploded = true;
  break;
}
```